# Email from Excel on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula, formula

I have a not-so-unique issue that I'm looking for a unique solution to.

Here's the super short version:
On a Mac, mailto VBA button doesn't work, but `HYPERLINK` function does. HYPERLINK returns `#VALUE!` error no matter how I try to `CONCAT` cells because # of email addresses is too high. Even if I do `=HYPERLINK(A1&A2&A3,"Click Here")` or something, the # of emails in A1, 2, and 3 is enough (10+) that I get the `#VALUE!` error because of the 255 limit.

Is there a way to bypass HYPERLINK character limits by using VBA but still retain the ability for the mailto function to work? Without requiring the end user to jump through hoops?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an api that will do the email for you , you just write the code that will look for get paramters and assembles the paramters accroding to your wish and do an email on a email of your choice .